# Mongoose Arbitrarily Changes Long Integer to Double

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, double, long-integer

I have a field in Mongoose defined as Mongoose type long (using the mongoose-long extension), which holds a 64-bit-integer. When I look at the field in an inspector such as MongoHub, I clearly see the value of the field to be `NumberLong(0)`, for example.

When I perform an $inc update for that field (using `mongooseInstance.update()`, where the delta of that field is `mongo.Long(x)`, when I look at the field in the inspector, it's then `NumberLong(x)`. So far, so good.

However, as soon as x is bigger than 2147483647 (2^31 -1), that is, starting with 2147483648 (2^31), the value of the field is suddenly `2147483648.0`, and not `NumberLong(2147483648)`. Mongoose literally chose to convert a long to a Double. When I perform the update query without mongoose, straight from the Mongo console, it works perfectly fine.

Also, I've tried checking what happens when the value that is stored initially is NumberLong(MAX_DOUBLE), which I assumed for Mongo would be 9218868437227405311 (if not, please tell me. I've been unable to find the max double value Mongo can store. Where can I find it? How do I find out? Am I missing something in the documentation?). When incrementing `NumberLong(9218868437227405311)` by `NumberLong(2147483648)` via Mongoose, the result was `9218868439374888960.0`, which is 9218868437227405311 + 2147483648 + 1. Where did that +1 come from? What's going on?

Please help.

EDIT: MVCE

> ExampleSchema.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongo = mongoose.mongo;
require('mongoose-long')(mongoose);

var exampleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  number: { type: mongoose.Types.Long },
});

mongoose.db.model('ExampleSchema', exampleSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.db.model('ExampleSchema');
```

> test.js

```
it('should test Longs', function() {
  var ExampleSchema = require('./ExampleSchema');
  var mongoose = require('mongoose');
  return ExampleSchema.create({ number: mongoose.mongo.Long.fromString('0') })
  .then(function(example) {
    return example.update({ $inc: { number: mongoose.mongo.Long.fromString('2147483648') } });
  })
  .then(function(update) {
    console.dir(update);
  });
});
```

Comment: Ok, I added one @JohnnyHK

Comment: Looks like a Mongoose bug to me as Mongoose should be preserving the `NumberLong` type of the `$inc` value when generating the native update command, but it's not.

Comment: @arik did you find a way to fix this?